# How can I limit the size of the Android source I need to download with "repo sync"?

Tags: git, download, android

<sup>I'm planning to leave for a country with a poor Internet connection, where I hope to do some software development.</sup>

I have been using `repo sync` to sync the Android source (and the CyanogenMod source on my AWS server).  But they are so large (> 30 GB) that I won't get them before I leave my country.

Is there any way I can exclude code from the tree?  I only need the Nexus 7 (wifi) (grouper) device.  Can I exclude any projects?  If so, how?

<sub>I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and repo.</sub>

<sub>(I am using Android tablets for educating children in very poor parts of the world.  I want to lock down the UI, so that children can only use the educational app(s).  As an anti-theft measure, I need to enable creation of a Wi-Fi hot spot and get the tablets to disable themselves if not connected to other tablets via Wi-Fi for 48 hours.)</sub>

Comment: Maybe you can clone with `--depth 0` so as to only get the latest revision? Or a sparse checkout: [Subdirectory Checkouts with git sparse-checkout » Code Nomad](http://jasonkarns.com/blog/subdirectory-checkouts-with-git-sparse-checkout/)

Comment: Agree with Nomad.  Big part of the source is the version history.  The device specific parts are not that much.  Also, instead of cloning the whole operating system, you could just get the git repositories for the part you are interested in.

Comment: Huge thanks, that is invaluable advice for someone on a terrible internet connection! In the 'repo' file, there is the section:
`group.add_option('--depth', type='int', default=None,
                 dest='depth',
                 help='create a shallow clone with given depth; see git clone')`
I have changed the default depth to 0 and restarted repo sync. I'll report back if this does what I want.

Comment: Not sure if this worked or not - full source was still 42GB, which someone says is the full tree. Can't confirm yet as I'm half way through ftp'ing it local.

Comment: Dear OP:  Your question is a good one.  However, you asked it on the wrong website.  If you had asked your question in the right place (on Stack Overflow), you would have gotten more and better answers.  I have re-asked [a similar question on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514459/downloading-the-android-source-code-more-quickly-by-doing-a-shallow-clone); please go there if you want to see better answers.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28379870/aosp-repo-sync-takes-too-long

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This might be too late. But:

- You could pass `--depth=1` to `repo init` to get a shallow clone.
- And you could use `repo sync -c` to checkout only the current branch.

Comment: It may be too late to help the original asker.  But it's not too late to help other people who also want to do a shallow clone of Android.

Comment: Great tip. One more tip: I use `repo sync -c -n -j 4 && repo sync -c -l -j 16` for faster syncing

Answer (score 0):

While repo sync is invoked, though a specific branch is selected, code from all branches are downloaded. In order to limit download size, you can manually download the code from github website. Like this, you can download code from the branch you want.

Comment: Sounds very inefficient, since Android's project tree has a lot of constituent Git repos, and trying to track them down and manually download would a huge time sink. Additionally this is not a generalized solution since not every project that uses repo is hosted on GitHub.