# Downloading only one version of AOSP Source, for only one device

Tags: git, android, download

I am using `repo` on my Raspberry Pi 3. The RPi's micro-sdcard is 16 gb. I have a 16 gb flash drive plugged in to it. (I can use a 32gb if I need to)

When I use

`repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-7.1.1_r1`

it downloads Nougat, but it downloads the source for Auto, Wear, and the source for normal Android Phones. How can I get it to download **ONLY** the Nougat AOSP Source code for Android **PHONES** - Excluding all else? I plan to build it for my Nexus 6p.

I have seen the following sites, but nothing helps:

[How can I limit the size of the Android source I need to download with "repo sync"?](https://superuser.com/questions/603547/how-can-i-limit-the-size-of-the-android-source-i-need-to-download-with-repo-syn)

http://zewaren.net/site/node/126

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945357/download-specific-android-source-code

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068388/how-do-you-download-a-specific-release-of-android-source-code-e-g-android-2-2

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This should make it:

```
repo sync -c --no-tags --no-clone-bundle -j`nproc`
```

Explanation of options:

```
repo sync -h
-c, --current-branch  fetch only current branch from server
--no-tags             don't fetch tags
--no-clone-bundle     disable use of /clone.bundle on HTTP/HTTPS
-j JOBS, --jobs=JOBS  projects to fetch simultaneously (default 4)
...
```